# Creating and Dropping Transient Tables in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I want to create and drop a temporary table in SQL Server, I would do something like this:

```
drop table if exists #part_1;

select
     whatever_columns
into
     #part_1
from
     table;
```

Does Snowflake have an equivalent? If so, what is it? I tried doing the following, but it is not working:

```
drop table if exists transient table part_1;

select
     whatever_columns
into
    transient part_1
from
    table
```

Comment: Transient tables and temporary tables are two different table types in Snowflake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `SELECT .. INTO` you can `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`:

```sql
drop table if exists part1;

create or replace transient table part1
as 
select 1 x, 2 y;
```